# Share Single Downloaded Artifact for multiple deployment stage in Release

Tags: azure-devops

Using Azure Devops.

1. During Build Process artifact get published
2. During Release it get downloaded. Now I have multiple stage and each stage has different no of steps.
3. Now when Stage get change it download artifact again.
4. Also within stage there are different no of deployment task and some of them download it again.

I want to make it such a process so possibly single stage can download artifact only once.

I want if there is already such task present.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Each phase has to download the artifacts that it needs to use for one very simple reason:

**They can run on different agents.** Each agent definitely has a different working folder. Some agents may be on totally different machines. Some agents may be a totally different operating system. The release has no way of anticipating any of that.

There is no guarantee that Stage A-Phase 1 and Stage A-Phase 2 and Stage B will run on the same agent. They can run in parallel on different agents, or they can run sequentially on different agents. Or they can all run sequentially on the same agent.

Thus, if a phase needs an artifact, it has to download it.

If a given phase doesn't need certain artifacts, you can configure which artifacts it will download by clicking on the phase and unchecking the artifacts that are unnecessary.

Comment: Is there a way so artifact publish or download once in local network and all other stage and step use copy of it.

Comment: You could, but you'd be introducing a race condition, because **builds and releases can run in parallel**.